# How to write mapping for an array of array in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field which is a 3d array, and don't want ES to index it.

The problem is how to write its type in mapping? Should I use `{index: false}` or `{enabled: false}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enabled` only at the mapping type level (i.e. for the whole type) or for `object` types.

Since you have an array, you simply need to use `index: false` instead.

The field can simply have a type `text` (+ `keyword` if you need exact matches) since the array will be flattened:

```
      "my_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But what type should be specified? If I omit type field, it complains that "No type specified for field [xxx]"

Comment: You need to set the type that matches the type of your data. Can you show a sample 3d array that you have?

Comment: It's something like this: {"my_field": [[["a-1", "a-2"], ["b-1", "b-2"]], [["c-1", "c-2"], ["d-1", "d-2"]]]}.